# Custom ShowDialog with more information than DialogResult

Tags: c#, .net, forms, showdialog

I need some more information than the traditional OK or Cancel states you get by ShowDialog, that is, some strings from the text boxes on my custom dialog form.

I wonder what the logic is. I would want to call it as such:

```
CustomDialog d = new CustomDialog();
DoStuffWith(d.ShowDialog().CustomString);
```

Of course, there has to be a custom class for the return result. Let's define it like this:

```
class CustomDialogResult
{
    public string CustomString { get; private set; }

    public CustomDialogResult(string customString)
    {
        this.CustomString = customString;
    }
}
```

Then we'd need to newverride the ShowDialog method in our CustomDialog : Form. I'm guessing we could start with some parented display of the form. Also, add an event handler to the OK button, which would set a result.

```
public CustomDialogResult CustomDialogResult { get; private set; }

private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Result = new CustomDialogResult(this.TextBoxCustom.Text);
    this.Close();
}

public CustomDialogResult ShowCustomDialog()
{
    this.Show(Form.ActiveForm);
}
```

As you can see, the problem resides in waiting for the OK button to be clicked, then to return this.Result. I could use Thread.Sleep(0) or a ManualResetEvent, but that would block the input on the dialog form. How would I go about this one? I know I could use uglier syntax, but if ShowDialog does it nicely, there has to be a way we can. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

It uses the standard OK result and simply exposes the extra information through properties and methods.

To do this yourself you just need to set your Ok Button's [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) to DialogResult.OK and then your calling form will interrogate your extra information through a property or method.

So the calling code looks like this

```
  CustomDialog d = new CustomDialog();

  if(d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  { 
      CustomDialogResult foo = d.CustomDialogResult;
      DoStuff(foo.CustomString); 
  }
```

Comment: D'oh! So easy. Sure will do this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just wrap a call to `ShowDialog()` in your `ShowCustomDialog()` method.  That way, you get all its "magic" for free.